# ältere Brüder or älteren Brüder?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

I can't understand why one sentence uses *ältere* and the other one uses *ältere**n***. Please help me with the grammar here.

> Das sind meine beiden ältere**n** Brüder. (Nominative)
>    Ich habe zwei ältere Brüder. (Akkusative)

Comment: Can you pinpoint your problem? What confuses you? https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:alt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an article or a pronoun before the adjective, you have to use weak declination:

- Nominative

  > Die älteren Brüder sind hier.
  >   Alle älteren Brüder sind hier.
  >   Meine älteren Brüder sind hier.
- Accusative

  > Ich sehe die älteren Brüder.
  >   Ich sehe alle älteren Brüder.
  >   Ich sehe meine älteren Brüder.

But if there is no article or pronoun, then you have to use strong declination (»zwei« is a numeral, i.e. neither an article nor a pronoun):

- Nominative

  > Einige ältere Brüder sind hier.
  >   Zwei ältere Brüder sind hier.
- Accusative

  > Ich sehe einige ältere Brüder.
  >   Ich sehe zwei ältere Brüder.

Comment: When using singular, an indefinite article also requires strong declension: "ein älterer Bruder" vs "der ältere Bruder".

Comment: Thank you, I don't know this rule before with strong and weak declination. German has a lot of rules :(.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru: Other languages have even more rules. German has 4 cases, Hungarian has 27. German has 3 grammatical genders, Suaheli has 22. German has 6 tenses but no aspects, if you count all combinations of tenses and aspects, you will find that English has 16 tenses and some Austronesian languages like Rapa have 19 tenses, while Japanese doesn't have any tenses at all. Most languages have 3 grammatical persons (1: I/we, 2: you, 3: he/she/it/they) but Greenlandic has a 4th person. German and English have "singular" and "plural", but both had a number called "dual" in ancient times.